# FirebaseListAdapter not populating Listview from Firebase Database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've been researching Firebase for a while and decided to give it a try.

I can't seem to figure out why my ListView is not populating. 
I can't seem to understand how the adapter looks for our query, for example, I want the string "Artist" and "Title" from my firebase database.

My POJO:

```
public class Song {

private String mTitle;
private String mArtist;

public Song(String title, String artist) {
    mTitle = title;
    mArtist = artist;

}

public Song(){
    //Needed for firebase
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return mArtist;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    mArtist = artist;
}
```

My Activity

```
public class player extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseListAdapter<Song> myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player2);

    ListView songListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songListView);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    myAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Song>(player.this, Song.class, R.layout.song_item, ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Song song, int position) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleItem)).setText(song.getTitle());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artistItem)).setText(song.getArtist());
        }
    };
    songListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


}
```

}

My database:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you create an adapter at a location, it will be populated with the direct child nodes under that location.

You attach the adapter to the root of the database, so your child node is `issue_1`. And in your data model `issue_1` does not have `artist` and `title` properties.

Simplest way to get the code working is to attach the adapter one level lower in the tree:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference issue1 = ref.child("issue_1");

myAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Song>(player.this, Song.class,
                                          R.layout.song_item, issue1) {
```

Comment: I tried doing this but get an error. 

"com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.puxil.mtrl.Song"

Thanks for the suggestion!